# Jumbotron Background Image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've tried everything and searched everywhere. But nothing seems to work.
It's such an easy problem to solve I think, I'm just not getting there alone.

I want to set a background image on my jumbotron, since I'm using bootstrap.

Here is what I did.

```
<div class="jumbotron center " > <!-- start jumbotron -->

  <div class="container">

    <div class="jb-text">
        <h1>This is an epic service</h1>
        <h3>Not really, just trying this thing out</h3>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-default" id="btn-custom"><a href="#">Start Your     <strong>Free</strong> Trial</a></button>

  </div> <!-- end container -->

</div> <!-- end jumbotron -->
```

And this is the CSS

```
.jumbotron{
    background-image: url('image/green-forest.jpg') no-repeat center center;

}
```

Unfortunately nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have used [background-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) instead of [background](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) property.

Comment: Yes! It's strange. I'm doing something wrong, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Did you inspect element with browser to see if the image is loaded correctly?

Comment: Yeah, thanks mate. That helped. The problem was I was using less and the css output was different than what I thought , so my url was incorrect. Such a noob. Thank you very much for your support mate. Grateful

Answer (score 2):

I was just having the same problem. Since my css file was contained within a stylesheets folder, and I stored images in a different folder, I had to change it to:

```
.jumbotron{
    background-image: url('../image/green-forest.jpg') no-repeat center center;
}
```

This is because your url is relative to the location of your css file, not your HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely a combination of two things:

- First, you have specified the `background-image` attribute. This would be fine if you hadn't added the other properties as well. So you should have rather used the `background` attribute here - as in the previous answer.
- Next, whether or not your `jumbotron` style actually applies also depends on the other in which you load the CSS files in your page. If you load your CSS file **before** the Bootstrap CSS, then the styles from the Bootstrap CSS file will probably override your style. In this case, your styles will not apply. So you should load you specific CSS file **after** the Bootstrap CSS file is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

```
.jumbotron{
    background-image: url(../image/green-forest.jpg); }
```

Please try this code for setting your image to the Jumbotron class.